# How to test if a React component contains another component with Tape and Enzyme?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, reactjs, enzyme

Suppose I have the following [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/index.html) component:

```
import React from 'react'
import AppBar from 'material-ui/lib/app-bar'

class NavBar extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <AppBar
          title='My NavBar Title'
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default NavBar
```

And I want to set up a test to make sure the user sees a [material-ui AppBar](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar) when the `NavBar` is rendered, using [Tape](https://github.com/substack/tape) and [Enzyme](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/index.html) for that:

```
import NavBar from './NavBar'
import React from 'react'
import test from 'tape'
// import { I don't know exactly what to import here. Maybe `shallow`? } from 'enzyme'

test('NavBar component test', (assert) => {
  test('I should see an AppBar', (assert) => {
    // How can I test for it?
    // Also, can I test only for the presence of `AppBar`, without
    // necessarily for the overriding of props? For example,
    // even if I actually have <AppBar title='My NavBar title' />,
    // can I test only for `AppBar`?
    assert.end()
  })
  assert.end()
})
```

How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't use tape and enzyme, but the question is more related to React testing tools according to my understanding.

Anyway tools have method: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#findallinrenderedtree

Which you can use to see whether the component was rendered like so:

```
const u = require('react-addons-test-utils');
const hasAppBar = u.findAllInRenderedTree(NavBar, (component) => {
   return u.isCompositeComponentWithType(component, AppBar);
});
```

Just make sure that AppBar is really the displayName of the component you are searching for.

You will get back an array of components which match the predicate, so you can either check whether length > 0.

Answer (score 17):

I got it. It is:

```
test('I should see one AppBar', (assert) => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<NavBar />)
  assert.equal(wrapper.find('AppBar').length === 1, true)
  assert.end()
})
```

The [`shallow`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html) function from `enzyme` returns a wrapper which has the method [`find`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html). `find` returns an object that has the property `length`. If I had two `AppBar`s in my component, `length` would be equal to `2`, so I can test it for `=== 1` to complete my test.

Comment: With Enzyme, you should also be able to write this using its matchers. 

So:

`assert.equal(wrapper.find('AppBar').length === 1, true)`

Could become:

`expect(wrapper.find('AppBar')).toHaveLength(1)`